# HTTP basic authentication URL with "@" in password

Tags: http, selenium, http-authentication, saucelabs

I'm trying to set up some selenium tests to our staging server using Sauce Labs. It's behind a basic http auth, so theoretically I could set the selenium URL to `http://user:password@www.stagesite.com`. *However,* the password contains a "@", causing all sorts of problems as you can imagine. I tried escaping it with a backslash but that did nothing from what I can tell.

So,

1. is there an alternative way to do http authentication using selenium, i.e., not via the URL. Or,
2. is there a way to use URL-based auth but somehow tell the browser that the "@" is part of the password?

Comment: Also, I *think* Selenium can still handle standard HTTP auth dialogs; maybe just try doing a record and see what you get log in via the prompt.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You just need to encode special characters like that before passing them as part of the URL, so `@` would need to be passed as `%40`, eg:

```
https://user:password%40www.example.com
```

(I typically use this - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ - for my en/decoding needs.)