# Selenium Java - How to log in with the @ sign Alert

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, webdriver, testng

I have a problem accessing the site where authentication in the form of an alert is required.
Photo: 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rd4V.png)

My data:
Login: login
Password: password@123

I set this address in the propertires file:

url=http://login:password@123@website.com

```
 driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
 driver.get(data.getData().getProperty("url"));
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 log.info("Successed Login ");
```

I can't access the page. The problem is probably because the @ sign is in the password. Unfortunately I can't change it. Is there any solution for this?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use some encoding to escape the character. According to this documentation on [RFC3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html), you can encode `@` using the `%40` character:

```
url= "http://login:password%40123@website.com"
```

Comment: Christine, thanks for the reply. The above solution does not want to work: /. It is treated as a normal string.

Comment: Interesting, as both of these solutions seems to describe your exact issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574841/http-basic-authentication-url-with-in-password and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718471/escaping-username-characters-in-basic-auth-urls