# Back slash (\) in url basic authentication

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, httprequest, amazon-cloudwatch, chrome-canary

I am creating a Canary in AWS Cloudwatch for a sharepoint website logging as a different user.

Trying pass username and password in url for Basic Authentication like below

```
       http://username:password@websiteurl.....?loginasanotheruser=true
```

The Problem is username contains backslash (\) in this format username = domain\user.

So, when i am passing request with username with backslash its treating as invalid url or saying page not found.

Can some one please suggest me what is the best possible way to send username with back slash. Is there is a way to escape back slash ?

Thanks in Advance.

Pram

Answer (score 1):

You may have to percent encoded the special characters.

```
\  ==>  %5C
```

More reference:

- [HTTP basic authentication URL with "@" in password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574841/http-basic-authentication-url-with-in-password)

BR